# How to using insert/update callback codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, callback, crud, grocery-crud

I have 3 tables, `tbl_reservasi`, `tbl_ruangan`, and `user`.

I want to update my `tbl_ruangan.status` from `Tersedia` to `Tidak Tersedia`.

Here's my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Reservation extends MY_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->push_breadcrumb('Reservation', 'reservation');
    // CRUD table
    $this->load->helper('crud');
    $crud = generate_crud('tbl_reservasi');
    $crud->set_subject('Reservasi');

    //Label Fields
    $crud->display_as('kdReservasi','Kode Reservasi');
    $crud->display_as('kd','Ruangan');
    $crud->display_as('id','User');
    $crud->display_as('tanggalMasuk','Tanggal Masuk');
    $crud->fields('kd','id','tanggalMasuk');
    $crud->required_fields('kd','id','tanggalMasuk');

    //Kolom Input dan Callbacks       
    $crud->set_relation('kd','tbl_ruangan','{kd} - {kdRuangan} - {jenis} - {namaRuangan}', array('status' => 'Tersedia'));
    $crud->set_relation('id','users','{id} - {email} - {first_name} {last_name}', array('active' => '1'));
    $crud->callback_after_insert(array($this, 'status_update'));

    //Cetak Halaman
    $this->mTitle = "Reservation";
    $this->mViewFile = '_partial/crud';
    $this->mViewData['crud_data'] = $crud->render();
}

function status_update($post_array,$primary_key)
    {
        $_update = array(
            "kd" => $primary_key,
            "status" => 'Tidak Tersedia'
        );
        $this->db->update('tbl_ruangan',$_update, array('kd' => $primary_key));
        return true;
    }
```

Everytime i insert data, inserting `ruangan`, `user`, and `tanggalMasuk` it doesn't directly change `status` to `Tidak Tersedia`. It changes after i insert 2 records with the same values.

All i want only if i insert record from `tbl_reservasi`, then `status` from `tbl_ruangan` change to `Tidak Tersedia`.